# java application URL client context

Tags: url

I have a application on say abc.com. I want various companies to signup on abc.com, so that I can allocate,the URL dedicated for them like client1.abc.com. For example client1.jira.com

Comment: its called a *subdomain*. Do you host your own website, or use a web hosting service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wan't a "true" subdomain, that's something you have to take up with your web host. Doing this involves adding entries to a DNS server (which is managed by your hosting service, not you).

You can, however, set it up so that all requests to `*.yourdomain.com` route to the same server, and then that server parses the actual request url and redirects accordingly. This is called a ***wildcard domain***.

So basically, when a client were to log into your site and choose their subdomain name, you'd just have to add it to your list of subdomain names that you check for. Essentially, every time a client makes a request to a subdomain, you'll iterate through your list, check to see if the request matches any entry in your list, and if it does, display the options for that subdomain.

And when a client adds a subdomain, you'll just have to add the subdomain to the list, and add logic for it however you want to do that. Note of course that this is an oversimplified version of what you'll really want to do.. This is just to give you the idea and get you started.

Comment: Tks Philip. The question was more towards java application-know-how. Lookin got solutions post all requests to *.yourdomain.com is directed to my server. Lets say client1 and client2 signup, they should be able to access their subdomain URLs(client1.yourdomain.com and client22.yourdomain.com) on the fly(no server startups needed).

Comment: @user1579906 lol I didn't see the java part, but I guess I'm not really understanding your question entirely

Comment: I am using jboss as app server. Spec: When a user sign up into the web application, he will get a custom domain like

http://username.mysite.com

How can i accomplish this in my web application, without restarting application or server. I am still developing the app. i have not hosted it yet.